# Python/Django app where urllib is blocked on Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, urllib, azure-waf

I am very new to Azure, so please go easy on me here.

I recently deployed a Python/Django app onto Azure. In the app, I use the Python library `urllib` to retrieve a file on the internet via its URL. I know the code is correct because the app works locally, but when I deploy it on Azure, the request is met by a 403 error which crashes the app: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Reading around, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514959/python-urllib-request-throws-403-in-azure-notebooks), it seems that Azure blocks `urllib` requests. So, I created a custom Web App Firewall (WAF) policy where I disabled all firewall rules, and miraculously the app started working! This is obviously not a permanent solution, so I'm asking if someone can help with one of the following, any of which should solve my issue:

1. Can someone tell me specifically which WAF rule, from [this Pastebin list](https://pastebin.com/6SbSEw3X), is the one blocking urllib requests? I can't find any documentation or description, beyond the short label, that explain what they do?
2. Is there a way I can create a WAF exclusion for `urllib` requests?
3. Is there an alternative to using `urllib` that doesn't run into Azure firewall issues?

Once again, I am very new to how Azure works, and I'm not too familiar with how `urllib` works either, so if you do reply (and thank you if you do), please explain stuff to me simply :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python urllib.request Throws 403 in Azure Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514959/python-urllib-request-throws-403-in-azure-notebooks)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/47223/azure-application-gateway-rule-id-913101-python-re.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using the library `requests`, instead of `urllib`, resolves the issue as Azure doesn't seem to block it. I don't know why this is the case, but if it works, I won't question it.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.